# Can a Titanium Grade 5 alloy produced by SLM have greater 'surface area' exposed?

Tags: electrochemistry, metal

I was doing an electrochemical test (LPR) and Titanium Grade 5 produced by AM respassivated oxide layer faster than the specimen produced with traditional manufacturing under identical experimental conditions. I am wondering if this can be explained with 'porosity' and being exposed to more 'surface area' as a result?

Regardless of the the porosity level, will the SLM sample be air tight? Only then would my guess here be wrong. I am assuming that the layers below get exposed to oxygen as well which is why I see the plateau (a flatter curve) for SLMed specimen.

I am trying to find a reason for the slightly better performance of the same material from a corrosion point of view when submerged in a specific liquid.

[image: Linear Polarization Resistance]

Comment: Now which, SLM or AM? There can be all kinds of differences in surface structure or trace impurities. *You*'ve got their data sheets.

Comment: Alloyed titanium ( grade 5 = 6 Al, 4 V) has lower corrosion resistance in corrosive environments than the unalloyed grades. I never saw porosity on any titanium surface with a microscope.

Comment: AM = SLM for the purpose of this question. So please treat the AM as SLM in the graph.